# cdn.sstatic.net is having me stare at a plain white browser

Tags: support, cdn, performance

Tried looking up "cdn.sstatic.net" on meta but found nothing recent. Whenever SO is slow to show up in the browser, it's because it's stuck waiting for "cdn.sstatic.net". Also in the most extreme slowliness cases (might not be related) every once in a while the site shows up apparently without any CSS styling on my smartphone (running Android 4.1.2, that never happened on my desktop computer).

[There is a similar meta question here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92452/cdn-sstatic-net-is-slowing-down-initial-page-loads), but it's from 2011 (with comments from last year saying it's still relevant) and if it's any use, I'm in eastern Canada (Québec).

[This one from last year also](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120191/waiting-for-cdn-sstatic-net-waits-too-much)

Is it a known issue? - this year I mean.

Comment: Anything like described in [Static content CDN is unreliable for me, often showing “hostname could not be found”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190958/static-content-cdn-is-unreliable-for-me-often-showing-hostname-could-not-be-fo)?

Comment: No, nothing *that* intense. It's just slow at apparently random times.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for other questions reporting this issue, there are plenty that have been posted recently. These five are from the past month alone, as is the one Arjan pointed out (which I didn't list again), [and there are plenty more from before July - e.g. six more in June](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=css%20cdn%20is%3aquestion):

[Stack Overflow is not loading properly in Chrome](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189001/stack-overflow-is-not-loading-properly-in-chrome)

[Stack Exchange sites not rendering static assets correctly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188785/stack-exchange-sites-not-rendering-static-assets-correctly)

[SSL certificate OCSP verification issue on cdn.sstatic.net, SO's JS/CSS not loading](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187469/ssl-certificate-ocsp-verification-issue-on-cdn-sstatic-net-sos-js-css-not-load)

[Server of statics (and thus CSS) is now HTTPS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187249/server-of-statics-and-thus-css-is-now-https)

[CSS for Stack Overflow site not showing up correctly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187204/css-for-so-site-not-showing-up-correctly)

In some cases the blame is on the browser, some intermediate service/filter (like IPrism), the ISP, the use of IPV6, etc. etc.

Comment: To me it's only been an intermittent minor annoyance - I just hit *reload* and it works most of the time. And the "white-out" is always < 5 seconds, in Chrome. Sorry for this *one more* duplicate...

Comment: Yep, I've seen the same thing from time to time. The CDN and/or the browser seems very sensitive to network resiliency.

Answer (score 1):

It happens when you set your computer to dual stack IPv4/IPv6. Turn off IPv6 and run only on IPv4 will solve the problem.

Comment: nope, ipv6 is disabled at both the browser and the kernel and the problem persists